# Why are my stocks still down after the nasdaq is reaching alltime highs

Tags: stocks

Down more than ever even tho it looks like nasdaq has recovered completely

Comment: Captain Obvious answer: Your stocks are down because they were sold off and  they're not the ones that participated in the rally.

Comment: What are the stocks in question?

Comment: Mostly ev, tech, and clean energy.

Comment: @MohamedElsayed For example?

Comment: NIO, FCEL, BNGO, ZOM, PLUG, AYRO, CTRM,

Comment: So really, you're talking about thinly-traded small stocks, some of them "penny" stocks or companies with little in the way of earnings or profits.  There's no immediate reason any of them would benefit from a general rise in the NASDAQ as nothing in their business models would seem to make them candidates for any rise in the short-term.  AYRO, for example, reported just $1.6 million in quarterly revenues and has a market cap of $189 million.  And sell interest is three times buy interest.  If they're all like this then little wonder they're flat compared to the rest of the market.

Comment: Because you didn't buy a 'NASDAQ' portfolio but some other stocks.

Comment: "Why has my whole family still died of COVID even after the politicians are saying it only has a 1% death rate?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just because the market overall is doing well and at record highs DOESN'T mean the ones you picked participated in that.  It's like looking at an index and using it as a broad measure of how all stocks should be doing - that's just a fiction.
Keep in mind that like the DOW, indexes are a composite view of a selection of stocks, not a measure of EVERY Stock.  The DOW is comprised of 30 companies out of HOW MANY that trade?  Even within that group, just because the DOW is up overall doesn't mean every stock in the index is doing well.  Each company used in the index is weighted differently based on a number of factors, so a 1-point move in IBM has a different effect on the DOW average than a 1-point move in Microsoft or some other component.
Apparently the stocks you chose are not doing well for reasons that have nothing whatsoever to do with the NASDAQ as a whole, so use the averages like DOW and NASDAQ as a general idea of the markets, not a true barometer of what your portfolio is doing.